# How to change termination protection by boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I want to teminate many AWS ec2 instance,then i use boto3 like this:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python 
#coding=utf8

import boto3
ec2 = boto3.resource(
    'ec2',
    aws_access_key_id="<AK>",
    aws_secret_access_key="<SK>",
    region_name='eu-central-1'
)

instances = ec2.instances.filter(
    Filters=[{'Name': 'instance-state-name', 'Values': ['stopped']}])

ids = ['id1','id2'.....'idn']
status = ec2.instances.filter(InstanceIds=ids).terminate()
print(status)
```

But I got a ERROR:

```py
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (OperationNotPermitted) when calling the TerminateInstances operation: The instance 'i-0f06b49c1f16dcfde' may not be terminated. Modify its 'disableApiTermination' instance attribute and try again.
```

please tell me how to modify the disableApiTermination.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `modify_attribute`. See the [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Instance.modify_attribute).

```
import boto3
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')

instances = ec2.instances.filter(
    Filters=[{'Name': 'instance-state-name', 'Values': ['stopped']}])

for instance in instances:
    print(instance.id)

# after choosing the instances to terminate:
ids = ['id1', 'id2']
for id in ids:
    ec2.Instance(id).modify_attribute(
        DisableApiTermination={
            'Value': False
        })
    ec2.Instance(id).terminate()
```

Comment: so sad,that not work.ERROR not change:botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (OperationNotPermitted) when calling the TerminateInstances operation: The instance 'i-0568d687b7fc6a9f6' may not be terminated. Modify its 'disableApiTermination' instance attribute and try again.
that is strange...

Comment: I modify a bit for the last line of my code. Please try again.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to previous answer, you can also use the following method from client module

```
client.modify_instance_attribute(InstanceId='string',Attribute="disableApiTermination",Value='True|False'
```